# How to pass input value on form submit in react

Tags: reactjs

On submit I want to pass input value that user enters to function and alert value of that field.
This is the code I got, I am stuck guys, I know this is rudimentary stuff but I am new to React so can someone explain this further.

Here is the code

```
class UserInput extends Component{
   onInputChange(event){
    alert(event.target.value);
   }


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onInputChange}>
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Image Search"
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    style={{minWidth:'500px'}}
                    type="text"
                    /><br></br>
                    <Button 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    >
                    Search
                    </Button>

                </form>
```

BTW this is Material UI TextField and Button elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onSubmit` prop you pass the `onInputChange` function to is 'triggered' when you push the submit button. What this gives you is the information when the user has submitted the form.

In order to pass values from inputs within the form, you need to store them in your component's state and change them accordingly when user modifies the input.

You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

And a solution to your problem:

```
    class UserInput extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

   onSubmit(event){
    alert('Form submitted:' + this.state.value);
   }


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <TextField
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Image Search"
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    style={{minWidth:'500px'}}
                    type="text"
                    /><br></br>
                    <Button 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    >
                    Search
                    </Button>

                </form>
```

Comment: Some thing I find is that you don't need to bind this if you use arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

In order to access input's value, you need to save it into the component's state.

I suggest you use functional components with React hooks instead of class components because the code with functional components looks much cleaner:

```
function UserInput(){
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
   setText(event.target.value);
  }

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(text);
  }

  return (
      <div>
          <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <TextField
              id="outlined-name"
              label="Image Search"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              style={{minWidth:'500px'}}
              type="text"
              onChange={onInputChange}
              /><br></br>
              <Button 
                variant="contained" 
                color="primary"
                type="submit"
              >
              Search
              </Button>

          </form>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Using Functional Components

export default function FormSubmit() {

```
    const [text, setText] = useState('')

    console.log("Text: ", text)

    const sendMessage = () => {

            // Insert Your Logic Here using "text" variable

    }

    return (

            <div>

                    <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />

                    <button onClick={() => sendMessage()}>Send Text</button>

            </div>

    )
```

}